# Sitemap for multiple languages

Tags: xml, sitemap, multilingual

I am using array variables to translate my site, but when i generate a xml sitemap, i get it like this:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://hublaalike.com/index.php</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://hublaalike.com/index.php?lang=en</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://hublaalike.com/index.php?lang=al</loc>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

How can i fix it so won't have conflicts or trouble?
Because basically index.php is same as index.php?lang=en
also when choose language, index.php?lang=en becomes index.php

Answer (score 0):

Please use something similar to this:

`<link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en" >
<link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de" >`

Detailed description can be found here: https://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site.html

Comment: Would you please take an example with my xml i wrote above? i still find it bit hard to understand and don't want to submit it messed up.